# inflate/deflate porting, recommend a source code

Tags: png, porting, deflate

I need to port the deflate/inflate algorithm used in the png IDAT chunk, with CM=8.

I read the documentation on how it works the zlib and deflate algorithm for compression but probably it will be better for me to follow the steps already done by someone else more experienced than me for the porting.

Therefore I'm looking for the easiest source code for the implementation of inflate/deflate. I can read C codes and similar.

Any recommendation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zlib provides some examples:

- "puff" is a simple C implementation of DEFLATE, that's provided with zlib in its "contrib" directory.  puff.c doesn't use zlib, and has about 875 lines, mostly comments.
- zlib also provides a simple implementation called "zpipe.c", which is in the "examples" directory, but you might not want that because zpipe depends upon zlib (since it's an example of how to use zlib).